# /usr/bin/nvidia-modprobe: unrecognized option: "-s"

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-settings

```
nvidia-smi
/usr/bin/nvidia-modprobe: unrecognized option: "-s"

ERROR: Invalid commandline, please run `/usr/bin/nvidia-modprobe --help` for usage information.

/usr/bin/nvidia-modprobe: unrecognized option: "-s"

ERROR: Invalid commandline, please run `/usr/bin/nvidia-modprobe --help` for usage information.

Tue Oct  6 22:37:24 2020      
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 166...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   49C    P8    17W / 125W |    547MiB /  5943MiB |     13%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1215      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 28MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1320      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               70MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2951      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                198MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3085      G   ...mviewer/tv_bin/TeamViewer        2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3086      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              137MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3762      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       27MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5431    C+G   ...al/lib/vmd/vmd_LINUXAMD64       74MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any idea on what to do?

Comment: Probably a version conflict with the Nvidia supplied CUDA files (driver 450.80.02 et al) and the files from the standard repositories (drver 450.66, etc.). cuda 10.1 with driver 450.66 nvidia-smi does not need the nvidia-modprobe, it's not even on my system.

Comment: @ubfan1 So, should I just upgrade the nvidia-driver.

Comment: The source of your 450.80 driver should supply a compatible nvidia-modprobe too.  Or use the Nvidia 450.66 supplied by the Ubuntu repositories (and if necessary the equivalent nvidia-modprobe, but since I don't have it, it may be optional). The main problem is that the Nvidia CUDA installs tend to have all sorts of dependencies that cause problems -- see this site for various solutions. I prefer to set my system up with its current supplied Nvidia drivers, and unpack the CUDA source where I want it, avoiding all package dependencies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem after recent update to 450.80.2. In my case the following got the issue resolved:

1. Add / enable PPA http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. Optionally verify candidates are available: `sudo apt-cache policy nvidia-modprobe`
4. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-modprobe=450.80.02-0ubuntu1`
5. Remove / disable PPA if you do not intend using it soon again.

Comment: Unable to add the PPA in the first place. Any idea?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why you cannot add the repository? Some error message perhaps? In the meantime, you can try to follow official nvidia [installation guide for Ubuntu](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ubuntu-installation): 3. Installing the CUDA public GPG key.

Comment: This would also solve the issue, without adding PPA. `wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/nvidia-modprobe_455.45.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb`
and then install with `sudo dpkg -i nvidia-modprobe_455.45.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb`. Obviously the correct version of modprobe for the nvidia driver you have installed.

Answer (score 10):

I also faced issue after updating my driver to 455.45.01, above instructions works,
This would also solve the issue, without adding PPA.

```
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/nvidia-modprobe_455.45.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

and then install with

```
sudo dpkg -i nvidia-modprobe_455.45.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me (basically it is Keivan's comment on [the accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1284847/576026), but downloading using https instead of http).

```bsh
# Change 'nvidia-modprobe_470.42.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb' below to the latest version at the time you execute (see the link to find it)    
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/nvidia-modprobe_470.42.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i nvidia-modprobe_470.42.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

I got that same message trying to run 'nvidia-smi' after updating, but then about 5 minutes later...no error message. I'm thinking the GPU had to "warm up" or the persistence daemon hadn't fully started. Anyway, it "fixed itself" without my having to do anything.

Comment: This is not really an answer, rather a opinion. Read [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19074/when-should-i-answer-and-when-should-i-comment) for more infos when to comment and when to answer

Answer (score 0):

These answers helped me.
Do not forget to select proper Ubuntu version. Mine is 20.04
So for me these commands worked:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu$(cat /etc/os-release | grep VERSION_ID | cut -b 13,14,16,17)/x86_64/nvidia-modprobe_$(nvidia-smi | grep Driver | awk '{print $6;}')-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i nvidia-modprobe_$(nvidia-smi | grep Driver | awk '{print $6;}')-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

That should work in more cases I think